# Kubernetes load balancer External IP pending

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, rabbitmq, kubernetes-pod

I create RabbitMQ cluster inside Kubernetes. I am trying to add loadbalancer. But I cant get the loadbalancer External-IP it is still pending.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  labels:
    run: rabbitmq
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 5672
    protocol: TCP
    name: mqtt
  - port: 15672
    protocol: TCP
    name: ui
  selector:
    run: rabbitmq
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: rabbitmq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq
        image: rabbitmq:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

And My load balancer is below. I gave loadbalancer 
nodePort is random,
port number is from kubernetes created RabbitMQ mqtt port number,
target port number is from kubernetes created RabbitMQ UI port number

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: loadbalanceservice
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
spec:
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31022
    port: 30601
    targetPort: 31533
```

Comment: what is your environment?

Comment: centos7 linux env

Comment: Is it on cloud or bare metal on prem?

Comment: it is just virtual machine and centos 7 installed that is it.

Answer (score 6):

service type [Loadbalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) only works on cloud providers which support external load balancers.Setting the type field to LoadBalancer provisions a load balancer for your Service.It's pending because the environment that you are in is not supporting Loadbalancer type of service.In a non cloud environment an easier option would be to use [nodeport](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) type service. Here is a [guide](https://www.google.com/url?client=internal-element-cse&cx=013288817511911618469:elfqqbqldzg&q=https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiwsIfu3tvnAhUE7XMBHUr6Dc8QFjABegQIABAC&usg=AOvVaw2xemJrr-YnxgclrhnJhrDU) on using Nodeport to access service from outside the cluster.

Comment: ok you write that I need to write IP:nodeport but. I deployed rabbitmq with replica 3. and rabbitmq is now inside three different machine. But when I am consuming from a mahine and this maxhine is down. I need to write another IP. and I dont want that. Which IP should I need to write. and which node port. Because there are three diffrerent node port.

Comment: if you create one Nodeport service nodeport will be only one and for IP you can use any nodes IP and you will have to change IP if that nodes IP changes

Comment: I think this is not the answer my question. because I wrote about loadbalancing, when loadbalancing is issue I dont need to change IP node for node

Comment: Do you have a load balancer service in your env?

Comment: I could give loadbalancer's IP and I can connect to loadbalancer and loadbalancer checks which node is up and connects to it

Comment: you want to point nginx to rabbitmq? where is the nginx running inside or outside kubernetes?

Comment: I am trying to add nginx but I dont know what is target port what is nodeport and is port number of nginx

Comment: I used metalLB nginx I add .yml                                                                
```apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata: 
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: | 
     address-pools:
     - name: default
       protocol: layer2
       address:
       - What IP should I add? ```

Comment: follow this https://collabnix.com/3-node-kubernetes-cluster-on-bare-metal-system-in-5-minutes/

Comment: In here > apiVersion: v1
> kind: ConfigMap
> metadata:
>   namespace: metallb-system
>   name: config
> data:
>   config: |
>     address-pools:
>     - name: default
>       protocol: layer2
>       addresses:
>       - 10.94.214.200-10.94.214.255
>
> EOF

Comment: so either you use nodport directly on raabitmq or Nodeport on nginx and use ingress to route traffic to rabbit or you use MetalLB...which one you want to use?

Comment: You need add the IP range of your nodes

Answer (score 3):

LoadBalancer service doesn't work on bare metal clusters. Your LoadBalancer service will act as NodePort service as well. You can use `nodeIP:nodePort` combination to access your service from outside the cluster.

If you do want an external IP with custom port combination to access your service, then look into [metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/) which implements support for LoadBalancer type services on bare metal clusters.